# Userdata ec2 is not excuted

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, user-data

I am setting up a web app through code pipeline. My cloud formation script is creating an ec2 instance. In that ec2 user data, I have written a logic to get a code from the s3 and copy the code in the ec2 and start the server. A web app is in Python Pyramid framework.

code pipeline is connected with GitHub. It creates a zip file and uploads to the s3 bucket. (That is all in a buildspec.yml file)

When I changed the user data script and run code pipeline it works fine.
But When I changed some web app(My code base) file and re-run the code pipeline. That change is not reflected.

This is for ubuntu ec2 instance.

```
    #cloud-boothook
    #!/bin/bash -xe
    echo "hello "
    exec > /etc/setup_log.txt 2> /etc/setup_err.txt
    sleep 5s
    echo "User_Data starts"
    rm -rf /home/ubuntu/c
    mkdir /home/ubuntu/c
    key=`aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/pipeline-name/MyApp/ --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
    aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/$key /home/ubuntu/c/
    cd /home/ubuntu/c
    zipname="$(cut -d'/' -f3 <<<"$key")"
    echo $zipname
    mv /home/ubuntu/c/$zipname /home/ubuntu/c/c.zip
    unzip -o /home/ubuntu/c/c.zip -d /home/ubuntu/c/
    echo $?
    python3 -m venv venv
    venv/bin/pip3 install -e .
    rm -rf cc.zip
    aws configure set default.region us-east-1
    venv/bin/pserve development.ini http_port=5000 &
```

The expected result is when I run core pipeline, every time user data script will execute.

Give me a suggestion, any other

Answer (score 1):

The User-Data script gets executed **exactly once** upon [instance creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). If you want to periodically synchronize your code changes to the instance you should think about implementing a CronJob in your User-Data script or use a service like AWS CodeDeploy to deploy new versions (this is the preferred approach).

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline uses a different S3 object for each pipeline execution artifact, so you can't hardcore a reference to it. You could publish the artifact to a fixed location. You might want to consider using CodeDeploy to deploy the latest version of your application.